# Can I train Gaussian Process hyperparameters on the subset of a large dataset?

Tags: regression, gaussian-process

I have a large simulated dataset uniformly drawn from the state space of a dynamic programming problem. I did some experiments and found that increasing my sample size does not change the hyperparameters of the kernel functions a lot. So, I wonder whether I can train the kernel of GP on a subset of my whole dataset while using the whole dataset to make predictions to improve the computation efficiency but still exploit the information from the whole dataset. Any input will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: short answer: "No, but actually yes". See here for more info: https://proceedings.neurips.cc/paper/2020/file/1cb524b5a3f3f82be4a7d954063c07e2-Paper.pdf

Comment: Hello John, thank you for your answer. Do you mind explaining the "no" part? What kind of issues would I encounter?

Comment: neural nets have a cost function that looks something like $\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i}(y_i-f(x_i))^2$. If we only keep some of the terms we have an unbiased estimate. OTOH, if you look at the marginal loglik optimized for a GP, we have this nasty $\log|\Sigma|$ term in there, which does not break down into a nice sum for us, nor does $y^\top\Sigma^{-1}y$. Conceptually, the issue is that we have marginalized over the "true" function value $f(x_i)$ at our sampling locations, which means that our $y_i$ are correlated.